# Force RxJava buffer to flush on signal

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I am writing an Android app using Rxjava, the app simply collects sensor data and stores them in files when a buffer is full. For this purpose, I am using a `PublishProcessor` that emits the value every time a sensor event is detected.

I Have the following helper classes:

```
interface RxVariableInterface<T,R>{
    var value : T
    val observable : R
}

//Value is received on subscribing
class ProcessablePublishVariable<T> (defaultValue: T) : RxVariableInterface<T,PublishProcessor<T>>{
    override var value: T = defaultValue
        set(value) {
            field = value
            observable.onNext(value)
        }
    override val observable = PublishProcessor.create<T>()
}

...

var imuProcessablePublishVariable  : ProcessablePublishVariable<SensorProto6> = ProcessablePublishVariable(SensorProto6( ... ))
```

When a sensor event occurs I just do the following:

```
imuProcessablePublishVariable.value = SensorProto6(...)
```

In the listener side, I've created an Observer which does the data packing in text files and subscribes with a buffer operator:

```
class MySubscriber<List<SensorProto6>> : Subscriber<List<SensorProto6>> {

    var subscription : Subscription? = null

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {
        Log.e("RxJavaHAndlerProcessor","${e.stackTrace}")
    }
    override fun onSubscribe(s: Subscription) {
        subscription = s
        subscription!!.request(1)
    }
    override fun onComplete() { ... }

    override fun onNext(t: List<SensorProto6>) {
         // Post the buffer list to the writer thread
         mWorkerHandler?.post(WriterRunnable(t, mContext,SensorProtos.SensorHeader.SensorType.IMU))
         subscription!!.request(1)
    }

}
...

imuProcessablePublishVariable.observable
     .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .buffer(500)
     .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
     .subscribe(mySubscriber)
```

Everything is working as expected, I receive lists of sensor readings containing 500 elements. Is there a way to flush the buffer and emits a partial list?

E.g. the user stops the app when the buffer is 70% full, I would like to retrieve the pending list without waiting for the buffer to be full. Is there another way to implement this functionality?

Comment: why buffering ?

Comment: for several reasons: since the producer is pretty fast compared to the consumer I have time to write the file and send it over the network while the other buffer is filling; each file should be big as the buffer and I found it as a pretty elegant and simple solution

Comment: have you tried it by time interval ? buffer each 20 sec for exemple (It depends on how much time you receive your 500 items)

Comment: @bubbles I am receiving at an almost fixed rate so buffering by time or number should be pretty similar. The problem arises when I have to clear the buffer before it is full without losing data